# Formula to get the difference between a number and a static one

Tags: excel-formula

Hello and thank you for your time, in the picture below, I need a formula in cell C5 to find the value needed to get to -3 (from cell B5)

I've been searching a lot and can not find something similar, I thank you all in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula in `C5`, copied down :

```
=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C$4," ",REPT(" ",50)),50)-B5
```

Comment: HOLY mother of god, that was GENIUS, I can't even begin to understand that, but it does work.

So the formula says to take the number on the right side of cell C4 (can I just say use -3 in the formula itself?)  and than substitute that by an empty string 50 time? it's so confusing, can't understand it at all, but thank you so much again.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Solution]

To me, the answer should be just as simple as `=-3-[Row Data]`...

Comment: This also worked like a charm Terry, thank you, although it made me feel really silly how I couldn't think of that, thanks again.